# How to say “running in place”?

Tags: phrase-requests

“Running in place”, meaning to exercise by doing the motion of running when one might (for some reason…) be unable to go anywhere.

One proposal I’ve heard is *kuri surloke*. But *surloke* has been used to mean “on-location”, as in catering or cinematography; if it seems clear in context, I’m okay with that, but I’m not sure it is clear.

*Kuri senmove* seems like nonsense, as is *kuri* with various adverbial forms of *halt-* (*halte, haltade, haltante*, etc.).

*Kuri nenien* means something else, but it made me wonder: *kuri senmove* would mean “run without moving (making any motion)”, which is nonsensical, but perhaps, “kuri senmoven” might be acceptable? Or *kuri senloken*?

Reading a physics text I got the sense that Esperanto doesn’t have good words for “motion” meaning a change of position as distinct from “motion” meaning, for instance, waving one’s hands around—that sort of motion is usually expressed via talking about traveling or using verbs of motion.

Comment: _kuri surloke_ is good! As for the two "motions", you could ask that as a new question. I'm not sure what it is you feel you cannot express in Esperanto.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani My search for _surloke_ found a use of “danci surloke”, but every other published use of it I could find meant “on-location”, not “in-place”.

As for what I meant by what I can express, take a look at, for instance, https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vektora_rapido — perhaps it is written poorly, but other physics texts I’ve seen also use circumlocutions to specify “change of position” as a thing separate from motions that could just be _gestuoj_.

Comment: Could you ask that in a new question? With two examples of what you would to say in English (the two different sentences) and how you think it folds into just one verb. It looks interesting, but some people might not see it buried in comments. By the way, that article could use some revision.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-to-one relation between any two languages, even less between English with lots of synonyms and Esperanto which tries to avoid them. So you should first little clarify what do you want to express with "running in place".

If taken literally, I understand it to mean moving feet like you were running but remaining more or less in the same spot. As you do in sport exercises when you test how quickly you can accelerate. This is *kuri surloke* or *senmove*.

If taken figuratively, I understand it to mean stagnation, lack of progress. There is a verb [*stagni*](http://vortaro.net/#stagni) which means

1. restadi senflua : *stagnanta akvo*
2. restadi senmova, senaga, malaktiva : *la komerco stagnas*

Or perhaps *senprogresa* could suit into your context.

Comment: Yes, I meant literally, for exercise.

Comment: And the problem here isn’t a lack of synonyms, it’s the opposite problem: in English, depending on context, the word “motion” means both formal motion—a change in location, the derivative of velocity—and conceptual motion. There’s no particular word meaning one and not the other. If the same is not true in Esperanto—if there are two words that are unambiguous—it’s unclear to me what those are.

Answer (score 1):

*kuri surloke* estas bona solvo.

Ekzemploj el [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com):

```
Li dancis surloke, centre de la rondo.

... ankoraŭ svarmis surloke konstrulaboristoj

la gasto faris kelkajn paŝojn surloke
```